# How to override datagrdiview col cell strings Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Actually I spent some time on the internet to look for a solution for my problem. I tried to look "override datagrdiview col cell strings" but I don't find any direct idea for this problem.

I read a xml file and  display data in the col[0] in this format and it's a list(based on numbers of items, it'll load):

`Config0
Config1
Config2
Config3
Config4
Config5`
..etc.. form the file.

I want to display it  in the GUI, like this:

`Config1
Config2
Config3
Config4
Config5
Config6` etc....
But when I write it back to the file, I want to write with the original data text.

How can i override the datagridview col cells string?? Please help me, thank you.

Please don't give me down vote,  Please show me some example...!

Comment: Why don't store it originally as `Config1 Config2 Config3 Config4 Config5 Config6`? Looks like you are trying to create work for yourself. Something like "If I eat my driver's license, what's the way to get it back?"

Comment: @ Neolisk: It's a configuration file, everythings start with `0`but for the user interface I need to display it from 1, 2 ,3..

Comment: Convert this XML file to another one, where everything is correct(in-memory), use that as a DataSource for your UI, perform changes, save and convert back. It will be much more simple to handle this way, than hacking into DataGridView. What you are asking for does not have any practical sense to me. For example, suppose you had car models listed. You want to replace all Ford with Mercedes, for user convenience. Why???!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [DataColumn.Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to create a separate calculated column, as long as you are not changing it in your DataGridView. I never used it myself, but it should be something similar to this:

```
yourNewColumn.Expression = "'config' + CONVERT(SUBSTRING(yourOriginalColumn, 7, 1),Int16)+1"
```

This code may need to be adjusted to account for variable length of your integer part.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the Tag property of the cells.
Maybe store some values in the Tags and display other data.

Comment: He wants to show different value from the one being actually stored.